# logcat has no content

Tags: android, logging

This has nothing to do with eclipse.  Every other question about logcat not displaying anything on this site is about eclipse, so far as I have found.  This is not one of them.

I have an LG G3.  It's rooted and bumped.  It's pestering me ALL THE DAMN TIME to update (there's apparently no way to shut this off with the Verizon model).  I really, really, REALLY want to use a custom ROM to end this pain.  Thing turns on the screen and leaves it that way until I notice and tell it to bug me sometime within the next 24 hours.

I set it up with Skydragon, which from what I can tell is the stock ROM de-bloated and slightly modified to run faster and more efficiently.

Apparently though it has no log.  I can connect to it with adb just fine.  I can upload apps and run them.  What I can't do is see anything at all in logcat.  I even tried opening the main log device on the phone, it was empty.

My best guess is that either the kernel doesn't have logging facilities in it, which would seem stupid so I doubt it, or the logging service isn't turned on (assuming there is one).  I don't see any log service file in the init.d directory (skydragon I believe uses init.d).

Anyone know what I need to do here to get logging working?  I'd sort of like to stick as close to stock as possible at least for the time being.  It's getting frustrating though.  Either I'm constantly arguing with the system upgrader, or can't debug my apps with logs.  Neither is what I'd call acceptable.

[I did try asking this same question in the skydragon thread at xda but got no reply.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-lg-g3/development/dec-9-skydragon-g3-vs985-kvt49l-vs98512b-t2967868/post57731587#post57731587)  It's been a week so I don't expect one.

Comment: Is there log available through adb shell ?

Comment: No.  No variation of logcat has any content.  Unless there's a different command than `logcat` to use in adb shell, there's no logs in adb shell.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get this going by selecting the stock kernel in the aurora install.  With this done the expected logcat content is there.  There may be a better answer, but it's yet to be provided.  I'll leave this open just in case, but this be here for those searching for WTF might be going wrong needing to fix it.